# Depends: libboost-XXX but it is not installable

Tags: ubuntu, boost, realsense

I am trying to install cubemos-SkeletonTracking SDK on Ubuntu 18.04 using `sudo apt-get install ./cubemos-SkeletonTracking_*.deb` but getting the following errors:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cubemos-skeleton-tracking-sdk : Depends: libboost-log1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libboost-program-options1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libboost-regex1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libboost-chrono1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libboost-date-time1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libboost-atomic1.65.1 but it is not installable
```

Tried `apt-get -f install`, installing the missing packages manually (N/A) etc. Also it still looks for 1.65.1 libboost even though I later installed 1.71.1...